# Determine if a given IP address is in an array of networks

Tags: ruby, arrays, networking

I'm trying to determine if a given IP is in an array of networks.  Using `include?` against an array of `IPAddr` objects does not seem to work (the if condition is never met), e.g.:

```
require 'ipaddr'

my_ipaddr = IPAddr.new("192.168.10.102")

# define our internal networks
internal = [IPAddr.new("192.168.50.1/24"), IPAddr.new("192.168.10.1/24")]

if internal.include?(my_ipaddr)
    puts "I'm in the internal network"
end
```

However, if I define a single network without an array, it works nicely:

```
internal = IPAddr.new("192.168.10.1/24")
```

Let me know if you need more info.  I'm new to ruby, so be kind :).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are asking Ruby to see if any of the objects in the array matches the IP address and they won't. IP networks are not the same as host IPs.

Instead you have to compare the host IP to an individual IP range and see if it is included.

See [`include?`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/ipaddr/rdoc/IPAddr.html#method-i-include-3F) in the IPAddr class:

```
internal.any? { |i| i.include?(my_ipaddr) }
```

Enumerable's `any?` returns true/false. Use `find` to get the first one instead:

```
internal.find { |i| i.include?(my_ipaddr) }
```

If you are doing lots of IP address manipulations or subnetting, look at the [IPAddress](https://github.com/bluemonk/ipaddress) gem. It is really nice.

Comment: Works nicely.  IPAddr seems to be sufficient for me, but I'll keep the [IPAddress](https://github.com/bluemonk/ipaddress) gem in mind if I need [some power](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NowdrL6fvb4).

Comment: Good. IPAddress would be a great candidate for replacing IPAddr, and, if I remember right, there was discussion about that. I think it's fallen to the side since, but it'd be a good thing for Ruby.

Answer (score 2):

The `IPAddr` class has its own `include?` method that is *very* different from `Array#include?`

http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/ipaddr/rdoc/IPAddr.html#method-i-include-3F

When you say `internal.include?` you are actually calling `Array#include?` which tests object equality. Obviously these are not the same objects, so the comparison fails.

What you actually want is to see if *any* of the `IPAddr` objects `include?` your `my_ipaddr` object

```
if internal.any? {|subnet| subnet.include?(my_ipaddr) }
    puts "I'm in the internal network"
end
```